# How to change letterbox/pillarbox strip color in UWP MediaPlayerElement

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

[image: letterbox]

I have video with strips (based on window size):

```
<MediaPlayerElement Stretch="Uniform">
```

I would like to replace black strips with white ones. How I can control color of these strips?
I have checked `global.xaml` file in the SDK, but styles are not there.

Comment: Hi, This part of the black is mainly controlled by `MediaPlayerPresenter`. The non-playing area is black (the color is not displayed). This is a common practice. There is currently no public API to set the background of the non-playing area.

Comment: Given that you can't change the background colour via an API, my suggestion would be try and resize the `MediaPlayerElement` to the size of the video, then place whatever background colour you want behind it. This would require you to add your own `TransportControls` if you need them?